# On "How to tell whether your programmers are under-performing"

Tags: discussion

How the question "[How to tell whether your programmers are under-performing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177167/how-to-tell-whether-your-programmers-are-under-performing)" amasses 17 votes and counting.... but is now closed. The close reason is "off topic".

As you can see, this question provides a lot of value to the community, and programmers, managers and everyone alike really love this kind of question/answers that won't usually be found in blog posts, books and so on.

In the name of community interest, can the Programmers moderators be so kind as to:

1. Reopen the question
2. And if you can't do this, move the question to an appropriate site, namely, [WorkPlace SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Required reading: **[The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)** - votes are not a reliable indication of the value. I for one find [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/177167/how-to-tell-whether-your-programmers-are-under-performing) valuable, but votes count has nothing to do with that

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that only option 2 is appropriate. It is very common on StackExchange sites for questions to be interesting to the users (and hence attract many up-votes) yet be inappropriate for the site in question.

This is very common on StackOverflow, for example, where many questions that are subjective and debate-provoking gain a lot of up-votes but are later closed or migrated to this site.

If I were you, I'd flag the question (*flag > it needs ♦ moderator attention > other...*) and suggest it is migrated.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree. I think it fits on P.SE or Workplace, and would be glad to see it stay on P.SE. I made one edit to try and clarify the question at hand. How to assess a programmer is a common theme on P.SE, this fits on P.SE in the same way as questions on interviewing techniques does.

Comment: A number of subjective and debatable questions are what make the site interesting. Some of the best questions on StackOverflow are the early heated debates. They give the site spice. Otherwise a site become repository of humdrum facts and answers, which does not build a community.

Comment: Hi @ChuckConway, unfortunately, questions that lead to debate or discussion are just simply not what Stack Exchange is about. Such questions tend to leave people with more questions than answers, and Stack Exchange is about finding answers. With that said, [chat] can be an excellent place to hold such discussions and debates. ;)

Comment: @jmort253 I disagree, on one of the stackexchange podcasts, Joel and Jeff, get into one of their many discussions on gaming theory. Jeff agrees that for a site to be successful, it must have a human component. Some of the "subjective" and "Hidden features of X", are healthy. As you point out, subjective questions, discussions and debates are not StackExchange's core objective, but without these types of questions sprinkled throughout the content, you don't have a community.